# Filtering sections of a table view using a segmented control

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm wondering what the best way is to filter out various sections in a table view using a segmented control in a toolbar.

Let's say, for example, I have a table view with cells in 3 different sections - Friday, Saturday, and Sunday. I also have a toolbar on top of the view with 4 segments - All, Friday, Saturday, and Sunday.  When 'All' is selected on the segmented control, all sections and cells in the table should be displayed.  When 'Friday' is selected on the segmented control, only cells in the Friday section should be displayed in the table.  And so on and so forth...

Where in the code for my table view controller can I make this happen?  I imagine it's a pretty simple thing to achieve, so are there any other examples of this that somebody can point me to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One place to do it is in your `UITableViewDataSource` code: give your data source access to your `UISegmentedControl`, letting it access the value of its `selectedSegmentIndex` property. There, your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` would be able to find out the appropriate number of rows by looking at the index and subtracting the count of inapplicable rows, and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` would be able to re-index the rows based on the current selection.

You may need to keep additional data structures in the model in order to support the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Specifically, you may want to add arrays for the three "special" days, so that the search for "what's row number three if Fridays is selected" does not need to loop through all the data in search of the third applicable row.